# How can I recover the source code from cdf file?

Tags: notebooks, import, cdf-format

by a mistake I have deleted the nb file by which the CDF was generated.

All required definitions were in one cell. If I remember the code looked like this:

```
Grid[{{Button[..],..}, 
  Dynamic[ ParametricPlot[..,Initialization:>{functions definitions}]]]
```

and later I selected the output cell and saved the selection by:
`File > CDF Export > Standalone`.

I can open the CDF in a text editor but it is highly unreadable and is difficult to extract all the math commands.

Comment: Opening in Mathematica just gives the graphics with controls and buttons and no cells to edit. Using Import[] gives the same what I see in the text editor.

Comment: You should not open CDF in text editor. You can easily corrupt it. As Kuba said, the code should still be in the CDF. You might have a cell set as closed and it needs to be opened that is all. If you put the CDF file somewhere, someone might be able to help better.

Comment: Open the .cdf in Mathematica. Then "save as" in the notebook .nb format. Now read it back into Mathematica. If it is not immediately visible, select all then enter and the cell will open as it executes.

Comment: I did it at first, but the notebook look the same like pure CDF and  has no cells to edit or to convert to anything.

Comment: @Kuba but I have NO output cell when I open CDF file (or the notebook (*.nb) obtained by "save as" on the CDF)

Comment: @Kuba what you mean by a cell? the content I see is note editable (was an option: Deployed->True) not selectable, not copyable and I can do nothing about it.

Comment: @sebqas You're right it's more complicated than I've thought.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit with a more compact code:**

```
CellPrint @ Cell[
  BoxData[
    StringReplace["$CellContext`" -> ""] @ ToString[ 
      ToExpression @ Get[pathToYourCDF][[1, 1, 1, 1]]
    , InputForm
    ] 
  ]
, "Input"
]
```

**Old answer:**

Open your cdf in Mathematica. Then open new Notebook and evaluate:

```
Select[Notebooks[], ("DocumentType" /. NotebookInformation[#]) =="CDF" &
      ][[ 1]] // NotebookGet // NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], #[[ 1]]] &

SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, CellContents]

NotebookApply[EvaluationNotebook[], 
              RowBox[{"InputForm", "[", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "]"}]]

SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellContents]

SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Comment: +1 Nice.  It should give the OP at least some of the code.  Code that evaluated  (e.g., outside of `Dynamic`) might be irrecoverable.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks and I agree. :)

Comment: You are great! I got exactly what I wanted. All parts are exactly the same like in my lost notebook. Many thanks /Dzięki/

Comment: The "new answer" with the "more compact code" works as advertised! Thanks