# How to extract the code from a cdf file?

Tags: cdf-format, conversion

I have several CDFs, and these bring interactive drawings with functions, how can I extract the code that generates them?

I have tried to follow some previous answers but it does not work for me, it is as if the code was protected

Comment: are these CDF's generated by Enterprise CDF? as far as I know, in standard CDF's, the code can not be encrypted. It is in the CDF. May be the cell is closed? Did you try to open all cells to see if the code shows?

Comment: @Nasser , Thanks , I will see him tomorrow, very late in my lands

Comment: Can you provide a sample CDF ?

Comment: Is this what you need: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48731/5478?